# $e^{i\theta}$ versus $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$

Tags: complex-numbers, big-list

I am teaching an basic university maths course, and have been thinking about the complex numbers part. Specifically, I was wondering why I should include Euler's formula in my course.

This led me to the following "big list" question, which I thought interesting.

> What can you do with $e^{i\theta}$ that is much harder/impossible with $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$?

For example, $e^{i\theta}$ makes it easy to see that $\operatorname{arg}(uv)=\operatorname{arg}(u)+\operatorname{arg}(v)$.

Comment: Top of my mind: computing $cos(n\theta)$ (or sin) as a binomial expansion is easier than computing it recursively.

Answer (score 4):

It makes De Moivre's Formula much more obvious. Also n-th roots.

Are these engineering students? It's very convenient for dealing with alternating current.

There's bound to be more, but these spring to mind first.

Also [*this*](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2852#comic)

Comment: not the engineers!

Answer (score 4):

Developing products of several terms is painful in the $\text{cis}$ notation as the number of terms grows exponentially.

Compare

$$e^{ia}e^{ib}e^{ic}=e^{i(a+b+c)}$$

to

$$(\cos(a)+i\sin(a))(\cos(b)+i\sin(b))(\cos(c)+i\sin(c))=\\
\cos(a)\cos(b)\cos(c)-\sin(a)\sin(b)\cos(c)-\sin(a)\sin(c)\cos(b)-\sin(b)\sin(c)\cos(a)+\\i\sin(a)\cos(b)\cos(c)+i\sin(b)\cos(a)\cos(c)+i\sin(c)\cos(a)\cos(b)-i\sin(a)\sin(b)\sin(c)=\\
\cos(a+b+c)+i\sin(a+b+c).$$

---

Now try by hand

$$\frac{e^{ia}e^{ib}}{e^{ic}e^{id}}=e^{i(a+b-c-d)}$$and let me know.

Comment: this is a great example! The formula with, say 10 arguments, must be very nicely amazingly ugly.

Comment: Yes, this compare with trading $x+iy$ for $z$, with the added burden of $\cos$ and $\sin$ repetitions.

Comment: So I computed it quickly with Mathematica for 10 arguments, it has > 1500 terms and the answer contains 79867 characters (thus does not fit into an MSE answer limited to 30k characters)

Comment: Should count $1024$ terms of $10$ factors each, hence $5120\ \cos$ and $5120\ \sin$.

Comment: Ok maybe there are some simplifications (or I made it wrong in mathematica).

Answer (score 2):

It becomes trivial to derive the multiple-angle or half-angle formulae u\sing Euler's identity. The geometric derivation is long-winded and painful to visualise, but it's easy if you use the fact that $\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}=\cos(\theta)$ and $\frac{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}{2}=i \sin(\theta)$, and just apply Euler's identity and the rules for exponents. For example:

$$\begin{align}i \sin(\alpha + \beta) & =\frac{e^{i(\alpha + \beta)}-e^{-i(\alpha + \beta)}}{2}
\\[1ex] &=\frac{e^{i\alpha}e^{i\beta}-e^{-i\alpha}e^{-i\beta}}{2}
\\[1ex] &=\frac{(\cos(\alpha) + i \sin(\alpha))(\cos(\beta) + i \sin(\beta))-(\cos(-\alpha) + i \sin(-\alpha))(\cos(-\beta) + i \sin(-\beta))}{2}
\\[1ex] &=\frac{(\cos(\alpha) + i \sin(\alpha))(\cos(\beta) + i \sin(\beta))-(\cos(\alpha) - i \sin(\alpha))(\cos(\beta) - i \sin(\beta))}{2}
\\[1ex] &=\frac{(\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+i \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)+i\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta))-(\cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-i \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta)-i\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)-\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta))}{2}
\\[1ex] &=\frac{2i \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + 2i\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)}{2}
\\[1ex] &=i(\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta))
\end{align}$$

Hence,

$$\sin(\alpha + \beta)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)$$

Comment: Yet easier to develop $e^{i(a+b)}=e^{ia}e^{ib}$ and take the imaginary part. (You can do it mentally.)

Answer (score 2):

- Calculating integrals like $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x^2}dx$$ is difficult without Euler's identity.
- The physics of waves and optics is greatly simplified.
- Fourier transforms are easier to compute and work with, and have a more intuitive meaning, I think.
- There are a lot of applications in quantum mechanics.
- Almost all trigonometric identities are easily derived from this.

Answer (score 1):

Complex Analysis uses a lot the logarithm. As you said with $e^{i\theta}$ you can talk more easily for the argument. The important thing is that a branch of the argument exists iff exist a branch of the logarithm.

Therefore, exponential goes with logarithm. Also of the expressions $z^a$ are exponential forms...